# Post request to normal route, not using API middleware

Tags: next.js, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

Below my pages directory i have a few routes (for example "/product/details").
I'm using getServerSideProps() to have the page render server side.

How can i send a POST request containing data in the body to this page directly?
The idea would be that i can do something like this:

```
export async function getServerSideProps(postData) {
    return {
        props: {postData.body},
    }
}
```

I've tried console logging "postData". I can see that the post request headers are being sent, but the request body is missing.

Thanks

Edit:
I'm doing the posting using Postman, and i'm sending a raw body of type JSON containing a single key:value. But as i said, the page doesn't seem to receive the posted data.

Here is a code snippet for how i'm sending a post request to a route using puppeteer:

```
      const page = await puppeteerConnection.newPage();
      await page.setRequestInterception(true);
      await page.once('request', (request) => {
        let data = {
          'method': 'POST',
          'postData': JSON.stringify(jsonData),
          'headers': {
            ...request.headers(),
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
        };
        request.continue(data);
        page.setRequestInterception(false);
      });
      await page.goto('pathToNextJSRoute');
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish with this? What's the expected response? Pages are typically the responses to `GET` requests (which have no body) and are HTML. If you want to do something else, say, create a resource as the result of the POST, you can use an API route instead which can return other response types like JSON.

Comment: Hi
The end goal is to have a bunch of different routes that rely on the data being posted to them to render. There's a node (actually nestjs) backend that fetches the data, has some business logic to decide which route to post to. This post to the route happens using puppeteer and headless chrome. So the route ultimately is opened in headless chrome, creates a screenshot and closes again. I hope you understand the idea.

Comment: What kind of data are you passing in the body? As Tyler said, you shouldn't be sending POST requests to pages. Could you not use query parameters to send whatever needs to be passed to `getServerSideProps`?

Comment: I'm sending JSON that sometimes can get rather big, so i can't really using query params for it. I've been testing ways to make this work for days now, but i'm starting to lose hope. I can't wrap my head around why its not working.

Answer (score 1):

`getServerSideProps()` accepts [a `context` parameter](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-server-side-props#context-parameter) (which you've named `postData` in your example) and one of the keys in that object (`req`) contains the request body you're looking for. It arrives as a readable stream of byte data, though, so you'll need to convert it first:

```js
const streamToString = async (stream) => {
  if (stream) {
    const chunks = [];
    for await (const chunk of stream) {
      chunks.push(Buffer.from(chunk));
    }
    return Buffer.concat(chunks).toString("utf-8");
  }
  return null;
};

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  let data = null;
  if (context.req.method === "POST") {
    const body = await streamToString(context.req);
    data = JSON.parse(body);
  }

  console.log(data);

  return {
    props: { data },
  };
}
```

Comment: Hi

I copy pasted your example but i still can't get it to work. I did some more checking and realized that i'm getting HTTP Error 405: Method not allowed. The code snippet you provided also has no output, because the posted data (json in this case) doesn't seem to actually get received.

Comment: @hawenig977 I was posting data to the route via Postman (like you mentioned in your edit) and output is being logged to my console with no errors. How are you posting data to the route?

Comment: I have an endpoint in my backend (nestjs) that i'm currently calling from Postman. The Backend fetches some data and eventually opens a headless chrome using puppeteer.
Puppeteer gives the option to navigate to a page and post data to it. I will edit my original question adding a code snippet.

More info:
I noticed that when navigating to a NEXTJS API route with the above described method, it works and i can retrieve the data. But when navigating to the route directly, the data is missing.

Comment: I've added my code snippet to the original question. Maybe it makes more sense now.
As i've mentioned, when using my code snippet to post to a nextjs API route, i can retrieve the data. But when posting to a "normal" nextjs route, it seems the data gets lost